# Tree-structured text editor / note-taker

Tags: gratis, windows-7, note-taking

Looking for a tree-structured hierarchical text editor / note-taker.

Requirements:

1. Freeware
2. Not ancientware (must have been updated during the last 3 years)
3. Support italics/bold text
4. Windows 7 SP1 compatible
5. Can successfully import [Treepad Lite](http://www.treepad.com/treepadfreeware/) files

[Cherrytree](http://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/) seems to be an obvious contender, but the memory footprint of it in Windows seems extremely large.

Comment: Have a look at OneNote: http://onenote.com

Comment: Cherrytree memory footprint was certainly reduced as they migrated from python to C++

Comment: @gagarine Thank you for the info.  Approximately when did that migration take place?  Also, any idea of the memory footprint on Windows now?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket they started porting cherrytree to C++ circa 2019. Don't know when the first stable C++ version was released, but it's quiet recent. I do not have access to a windows machine. Give it a try :).

Comment: @gagarine Thank you for the follow-up.  I'm looking forward to trying it again.  Is it now in C++ for all supported platforms?

Answer (score 3):

You may try:

- [Wunderlist](https://www.wunderlist.com/) (note-taker for mobile and desktop)
- [KeyNote](https://web.archive.org/web/20171107065257/http://www.tranglos.com:80/free/keynote.html) [[code](https://github.com/dpradov/keynote-nf)] (it supports tree style editing),
- [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/) (notebooks and tags which can be tree organised),
- [TreeSheets](http://treesheets.com/) (it's table based),
- [The Guide](http://theguide.sourceforge.net/index.html) (file format is human readable like XML),
- [wikidPad](http://wikidpad.sourceforge.net/) (wiki-like editor),
- [Zim](http://zim-wiki.org/) (notes are saved as text files in folder hierarchies),
- [Treepad Lite](http://www.treepad.com/treepadfreeware/),
- [2do](http://www.antp.be/software/misc/) (Notes management),
- [Things](https://culturedcode.com/things/) (task management for Mac & iOS),

<sup>Source: [Simple tree notepad like editor](https://superuser.com/questions/83417/simple-tree-notepad-like-editor) at superuser SE</sup>

For more details, check [Comparison of Outliners](http://www.marktaw.com/reviews/Outliners.html).

Comment: Thank you.  I'll take a look.  Note that Treepad Lite is not an option because it does not support bold or italic text and is certainly ancientware, with no updates in over 5 years.

Answer (score 2):

### [Treeline](http://treeline.bellz.org/index.html)

Treeline is a very nice cross-platform (Win 7, 8; Linux) hierarchical notes manager. It is similar to Treepad (as the author himself notes).

[image: Treeline screenshot]

As for OP's requirements:

1. [image: Yes] Freeware
2. [image: Yes] Not ancientware (must have been updated during the last 3 years)
3. [image: Yes] Support italics/bold text | **and more besides**
4. [image: Yes] Windows 7 SP1 compatible
5. [image: Note] Can successfully import Treepad Lite files | **Not sure** - Treeline can import "plain text, tab-indented text and tab-delimited table files" as well as "generic XML files" (and import/export its own HTML); Treepad Lite can export (according to the online documentation) HTML and a "Treepad Lite file". There might be something compatible in there, but I'm not sure.

It ticks enough boxes to be worth investigation, at any rate. I use it from time to time under Ubuntu and enjoy having it in the "toolkit".

Comment: Nice bullet points. Is that kind of a SR standard?

Comment: @Thomas I'm sure it's **not** an SR standard! You can see the [meta-Q&A](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/581/435) where this was concocted with some helpful guidance notes on usage in the comments. I find it very easy to use and a quick visual guide to the requirements list.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Workflowy](https://workflowy.com/)
It's web based, works on mobile and offline too. You can share bullets.

Meets most requirements:

1. Freemium. Free gets 500 new bullets/month, no password protected sharing, no auto-backup to Dropbox.
2. Stable, under active development
3. Supports italics/bold text
4. Web based, so supports all OSes with modern browsers
5. You might be able to simply paste your old data to import it.

Comment: It's very high quality and they are thinking the right way about this imo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this web app
https://webnote.in

Online notepad on the web for all devices with flexible tree-like structure.

Currently not supported:

- italics/bold text
- import Treepad Lite files